# \ref* with Beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref, cross-referencing

When I use `\ref*{xx}` in `beamer`, it gives me an error: "`pdfTeX warning (dest): name{*} has been referenced but does not exist`."  Does `beamer` fool with it, or what am I missing?

If I run a regular MWE it works great.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Second}
\lipsum[4-5]
Label \label{jh}

\section{Third}
\lipsum[6-9]

Reference: \ref*{jh}
\end{document}
```

It prints a "2" there, without a hyper-reference.

But in `beamer`, my mwe gives me the error I mentioned at the start.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\section{test section}
\begin{frame}
  Label: \label{jh}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Reference: \ref*{jh}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A regular `\ref` (no star) works fine. It prints the reference, and makes it hyper also.

I have downloaded `beamer` from CTAN today, and I downloaded `oberdiek` also, because I was getting warnings about the date of some loaded packages, which I have resolved.  Beyond that, I have the TeXLive 2009 that comes with Ubuntu 10.04's package manager.

(FWIW, I want `\ref*` because the references come from another document courtesy of `xr.sty`.)

Comment: Right, `beamer.cls`does not provide a `\ref*` command. You have to define it yourself.

Comment: @Daniel, that was my first thought as well, but beamer loads hyperref and hyperref defines \ref* so arguably it should work, but then beamer redefines \ref again....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`beamer` and `hyperref` (as loaded by `beamer`)  appear to get into a tangle each saving an "original" version of `\ref` and each layering on extra functionality.

This tips things back in the direction of `hyperref`'s definition, I'm not sure how much `beamer` functionality it loses, but it seems to work on this example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

{\def\protect{\global\let\YesIMeanThisRef}\ref}

\AtBeginDocument{\def\ref{\protect\YesIMeanThisRef}}

\begin{document}

\section{test section}
\begin{frame}
  Label: \label{jh}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Reference: \ref*{jh}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Elaborating on David's answer, [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) *does* modify `\ref`, just like most other macros and environments. Within [`beameroverlay.sty`](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseoverlay.sty), the following is executed:

```
\AtBeginDocument
{
  \let\beamer@origref=\ref
  \long\def\ref#1{\hyperlink{#1}{\beamer@origref{#1}}}
}
```

removing the starred capability of `\ref` (since `\hyperlink{*}{...}` has no meaning). Here's a minimal example that refines `\reff` which returns the original starred-variant. I'm sure you can also redefine `\ref` in this way.

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\reff}{s m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Check for starred variant
    {\beamer@origref{#2}}% \reff*
    {\hyperlink{#2}{\beamer@origref{#2}}}% \reff
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{test section}
\begin{frame}
  Label: \label{jh}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Reference: \ref{jh}, \reff{jh}, \reff*{jh}
\end{frame}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Thank you, David and Werner.  I particularly appreciate the confirmation that it is not something I am doing wrong, or something with my setup.  I have reported the problem as a bug on the bitbucket.org beamer archive.

Comment: I will have to do this by hand in `beamer`, as I can't require `xparse` there :-)